# "Unable to detect database type" error while connecting to Denodo from Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, denodo

I am trying to connect to Denodo 8 using spring boot. I have configured below properties in the test.yml file. During the application startup, I see the error - "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type" and application fails to start.

spring:
datasource:
driver-class-name: com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:vdb://xxxx:xxxx/xxxx
username: xxxx
password: xxxx

I want to connect to the Denodo 8 using spring boot with the above configuration. I tried to connect to the same Denodo configuration as below in plain Java class without any issues. Issue is with only Spring boot config.

Class.forName(com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver);

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:vdb://xxxx:xxxx/xxxx?username=xxxx&password=xxxx);